# Unobstrusive pseudo-classes and attribute selectors emulation in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to emulate some pseudo-classes and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6 and 7, such as `:focus`, `:hover` or `[type=text]`. So far, I've managed to add a class name to the affected elements:

```
$("input, textarea, select")
.hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
})
.focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass("focus");
})
.blur(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("focus");
});

$("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("text");
});
```

However, I'm still forced to duplicate selector in my style sheets:

```
textarea:focus, textarea.focus{
}
```

And, to make things worse, IE6 seems to ignore *all* the selectors when it finds an attribute:

```
input[type=text], input.text{
    /* IE6 ignores this */
}
```

And, of course, IE6 ignores selectors with multiple classes:

```
input.text.focus{
    /* IE6 ignores this */
}
```

So I'm likely to end up with this mess:

```
input[type=text]{
    /* Rules here */
}
input.text{
    /* Same rules again */
}
input[type=text]:focus{
}
input.text_and_focus{
}
input.text_and_hover{
}
input.text_and_focus_and_hover{
}
```

My question: is there any way to read the rules or computed style defined for a CSS selector and apply it to certain elements, so I only need to maintain one set of standard CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this lovely piece of software:

- [ie-css3.js](http://www.keithclark.co.uk/labs/ie-css3/) CSS3 pseudo-class selector emulation for Internet Explorer 5.5 - 8

It basically covers my requirements (unobtrusive code that doesn't require specific CSS rules), although it doesn't emulate `input[type=text]`.

If you know about something else on this line, feel free to add a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already depending on javascript with your styles (otherwise, neither `:focus` or `.focus` work in IE6), I advice you to use `IE7.js` by Dean Edwards, which js-enhance ie6.

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: I used that library some years ago and it's sort of overkill. It performs really slowly because it's very ambitious: it fixes rendering bugs and it emulates lots of CSS3 stuff I don't really need. Considering that I'm already using jQuery for the site functionality, I guess poor IE6 wouldn't be able to cope with it. Thanks for the tip, anyway. I thought IE7 was abandoned and I'm glad to see it's not.

Comment: I used `IE7.js` with `jQuery` before and if your server isn't very slow, it works okay - i mean, you have less work, your site is 'mostly' IE6-compatible and the world is nice again :)